# Apps randomly dowloaded (Mobility Print and Zoom)

Tags: macos, applications

One day, I found 2 apps in launcher that I never downloaded: Mobility Print and Zoom.

I downloaded the Zoom app from Zoom.us

[image]

but now I also see this version (which I didn't download) from some reason:

[image]

I also see this (which I also definitely didn't download):

[image]

This was not an issue a couple days ago - they only appeared today. Does anyone else have these apps randomly downloaded? Will deleting them do any harm?

Comment: Is this a company computer? If so, IT may have installed these remotely.

Comment: @JBallin no, it's a personal computer. A few days ago, I got Mac OS re-installed, so I'm in the process of re-downloading apps. I did not download zoom or mobility print, but today they appeared when I opened launcher (was not there yesterday)

Comment: Is mobility print something you’ve used in the past? That’s much less common than Zoom IMO

Comment: @JBallin no, I've never heard of it. It doesn't seem to be causing any issues though, but weird that it's installed

Comment: PrintMobility is required by some schools and businesses to use their printers. Did you install Chromium extensions or Chromium web apps for these programs? If not, it could be malware. In my personal opinion, if you didn't install Chromium apps for these (which seems likely to me), you may want to find some free anti-malware like malwarebytes and run a quick scan, then uninstall the anti-virus.

Comment: Wording is odd "I got Mac OS re-installed" Who reinstalled macOS?